# Slick Texture loader and glBlendFunc interfering

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I have an issue regarding LWJGL and Slick

If I import a texture using Slick while having alpha blending enabled, the display will stop rendering!

Here is the code. Upon start it will simply render a purple square. Once the button T is pressed it will simply import the texture. Although i never actually bind the texture, the screen still turns black!

Here is my code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_BLEND;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
    Display.create();
    Game game = new Game();
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        game.update();
    }
    game.close();
}

public Game() {
    initGL();

}

Texture boxTexture;

public void update() {
    clearGL();

    // Use the texture!
    GL11.glColor3f(0.4f, 0.2f, 0.9f);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);

    GL11.glVertex2f(140, 100);

    GL11.glVertex2f(140, 140);

    GL11.glVertex2f(100, 140);
    GL11.glEnd();

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_T))
    {
        try {
            boxTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("png",
                    ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/ps.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Display.update();
}

public void close() {
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}

public void initGL() {
    // Enable Alpha Blending
     GL11.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
     GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 

    // Opengl init
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 500, 0, 500, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    // Enable textures
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

public void clearGL() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}
}
```

Comment: If you never bind a texture, then you should not enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` that is going to produce undefined results. If you're seeing a black screen that's probably because the color `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` is being assigned to everything.

Answer (score 0):

`TextureLoader.getTexture()` binds the texture. If you look at the Slick [source code](https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/opengl/InternalTextureLoader.java), you will find the following line in the `getTexture()` method of the `InternalTextureLoader` class:

```
GL.glBindTexture(target, textureID);
```

It pretty much has to bind the texture, since it needs to call functions like `glTexImage2D()` to load the texture.

So you will actually use texturing after calling this function, since you now have a texture bound, and you enabled texturing in your own code:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

To see the texture image, you'll need to perform additional steps, like specify texture coordinates.